# Finding length of items from a list

Tags: python, arrays

I have two list in a python

```
list1=['12aa','2a','c2']

list2=['2ac','c2a','1ac']
```

First- Finding combinations of each two item from list1.

Second- Finding combinations of each two item from list2.

Third- Finding combinations of each two items from list1 and list2

Fourth- Calculating each combinations total length

Advice and help in Python is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what the answer should be for your example data and how you arrived at that answer? It will be easier to understand your question if you demonstrate it with a specific example of what you want to happen.

Comment: "Solution in **PYTHON**"??? That sounds a bit demanding.

Comment: I was just doing a practice not any homework, sorry for my inappropriate words which sounds demanding. I have edited question again and make it precise. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools as it

list1=['12aa','2a','c2']
list2=['2ac','c2a','1ac']

# First- Finding combinations of each two item from list1.
first = list(it.combinations(list1, 2))

# Second- Finding combinations of each two item from list2.
second = list(it.combinations(list2, 2))

# Third- Finding combinations of each two items from list1 and list2
third = list(it.product(list1, list2))

# Fourth- Calculating each combinations total length
for combination in first: # first, second, third
    print combination, len(''.join(combination))
```

Comment: Actually, I want to produce combinations of each two item within a list and total characters in an individual combinations.  Second, I want to produce combinations of each two items from list1 and list2 and total characters in an individual combinations.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I faced another problem. Suppose from our example list1 we got 3 combinations from three item. Now, I want to pass that individual combination into a function and want to know first item and second item for another operation but not messing up with previous problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your last comment. Could you just add an edit to your original question together with an example?

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using combination? Because I figure out that when I try to run python file in other application terminal then it doesn't recognize combination(). Thank you

Comment: If you are using Python older than 2.6, please check here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations for a replacement function for combinations.

Comment: @eumiro- I have tried like you said, but my mine problem is to generate pairwise comparision of list 1, list2 and between list1 & list2. I was trying to run python script in pymol. But pymol doesn't seems to recognize itertools.combinations()